# TScrollBox without scrollbars

Tags: delphi

I want to dynamically create some buttons in a TScrollBox (that has VertScrollBar.Vissible= False).

I want to programmatically bring some of those buttons in view, so I would like to use something like:

```
  ScrollBox.VertScrollBar.Position:= i; //Does not work
```

However, the box won't scroll to the indicated position unless the VertScrollBar.Vissible= True.
Note: ScrollBy() works, but I don't want to use that.

How to circumvent this behavior?

(A "solution" would be to let the scrollbars visible and hide them outside the screen (place the scrollbox in a panel))

---

Code:

```
unit UnitVert;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation {$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position:= -20;
  //ScrollBox1.ScrollBy(0, -20);     //Works
end;

end.

object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 336
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 176
    Top = 75
    Width = 283
    Height = 203
    HorzScrollBar.Visible = False
    VertScrollBar.Visible = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 188
      Top = 132
      Width = 123
      Height = 99
      Caption = 'Dummy'
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 26
    Top = 50
    Width = 111
    Height = 51
    Caption = 'Test'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try ScrollBox.ScrollBy(0,-x)?

Comment: Where are your 2 buttons in that code? Why do you think a scrollbar can have a negative position? In other words: do it with the two buttons you already mentioned, do it with `.ScrollBy` in a relative way. And please put more focus on your overall question in terms of consistency.

Comment: @AmigoJack - The position of the buttons is already shown in the code I posted. One of the buttons is on the form the other is in the scrollbox.

Comment: Make the scrollbars visible just before you perform the repositioning and then make them visible immediately after the repositioning.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but it might introduce flicker. I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @FreddieBell - I tried it. Not only that it flicker, but it also won't scroll :) Making VertScrollBar.Visible= False at runtime, will force VertScrollBar.Position to zero! Strangely, this does happen at design time also.

Comment: @ServerOverflow: IMHO, the `TScrollBox` is a GUI control whose sole purpose is to let the user scroll using scroll bars (or mouse wheel). I think you should reconsider your design.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Yes. Sadly, it looks it is like you said. However, it would have been nice not to enforce the current behavior. It wouldn't have affected the functionality of the control. Just do the scroll, no matter if the scrollbar is visible or not. In the end ScrollBy is working!

Answer (score 0):

### Works as expected

Cannot reproduce your issue with D7 on Win7:

```delphi
Scrollbox1.HorzScrollBar.Visible:= FALSE;
Scrollbox1.VertScrollBar.Visible:= FALSE;
Scrollbox1.ScrollBy( -30, -45 );
```

...moves the viewport 30 px to the left and 45 px to the top. Also note that the first parameter is X (horizontal) and the second parameter is Y (vertical) - actually anything I've seen in life was always in the X,Y order.

### Why invisible scrollbars won't work

The method `TWinControl.ScrollBy()` includes this code:

```delphi
IsVisible := (FHandle <> 0) and IsWindowVisible(FHandle);
if IsVisible then ScrollWindow(FHandle, DeltaX, DeltaY, nil, nil);
```

...which means: it is essentially using the WinAPI's [`ScrollWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindow) function. Changing the position of one of the scroll**bar**s executes `TControlScrollBar.SetPosition()`, which in turn calls `.ScrollBy()` again for just one dimension:

```delphi
OldPos := FPosition;
if Kind = sbHorizontal then
  FControl.ScrollBy(OldPos - Value, 0) else
  FControl.ScrollBy(0, OldPos - Value);
```

...and since this time the parent control is the scroll**bar** (not the scroll**box**) its invisibility prevents the WinAPI function from being called. Content wise there's no gain in using scrollbars - they just conveniently remember what you already scrolled.

Comment: Well, the OP tried `VertScrollBar.Position:= x`, not `ScrollBy`.

Comment: No, both. Hence his fictional code with `or`.

Comment: Try with VertScrollBar.Position:= something. It will not work (at least not in Delphi 10.4).
I posted also the most basic example possible.

Comment: @AmigoJack: My bad, don't know how I could have missed that. Sorry!